# How to remove extra space inside textarea

Tags: html, textarea, whitespace

I have a textarea which displays some data from "history" column in my database.
For unknown reason there is nearly 1.5 line of extra space before the text. Anyone can give me some idea why does it happen?
Here is my HTML piece:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th > History:</th>
      <td>
        <textarea style="margin-left:90px";  name="history"cols="80"label="notes"rows="4"wrap="virtual"> 
        <?php echo $my_class->history;?></textarea>
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

You can see the problem here:[image]

Comment: Tried trimming `$my_class->history` in the echo?

Comment: I did try it but it doesn't sort that issue

Comment: Try reading answer from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824681/textarea-whitespaces?rq=1

Comment: Its because your php tag is on a newline. It is reading in the whitespace from where <textarea> ends until php tag opens. Put this all on one line to fix

Comment: You are right I-LOVE-2-REVIVE. Problem sorted

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Its because your php tag is on a newline. It is reading in the whitespace from where  `<textarea>` ends until php tag opens. Put this all on one line to fix.

Comment: Or for those still finding this question: use the CSS `white-space: normal` or (or any of the other collapsing rules)

Comment: I tried this one line solution but Mike'Pomax'Kamermans additional css rule worked for me. Thanks

Comment: "white-space: normal" won't remove the spaces, tabs and new-lines. It just won't show them, but they will remain on the field value.

Answer (score 6):

Just put your php open tag right after the textarea close tag.. Dont use line break.. And close php exactly before  (as you have done).. This will erase all the whitespaces..

Answer (score 6):

Put this all on one line for fix this issue.Make your code like this.

```
<textarea style="margin-left:90px";name="history"cols="80"label="notes"rows="4"wrap="virtual"><?php echo $my_class->history;?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 6):

I know its late but may help others.

use this when document indentation is required.

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $('textarea').each(function(){
            $(this).val($(this).val().trim());
        }
    );
});
```

[Same Question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44773825/3775083](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44773825/3775083)

Answer (score 2):

`$('textarea').val($('textarea').val().trim())`
This did the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem but I found an answer of this question. When you write php code between textarea in another line or in new line then this problem occurs

To fix this problem write php code and textarea in one line

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th > History:</th>
      <td>
        **<textarea name="history"cols="80" label="notes"rows="4" wrap="virtual"><?php echo $my_class->history;?></textarea>**
      </td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can break the opening tag as much as you want, like

`<textarea id="COMMENTS"` 
   `name="COMMENTS"`
   `rows="3"`
`>`
as long as the
`</textarea>`
does not have blank spaces to the left

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).